# HTML templates and PHP dynamic templating

Tags: php, html, templates

I know maybe this question may have been asked before, so I'm so sorry to be redundant.
I want to know what are the differences between HTML templates and Dynamic Templating such as PHP Templates. I'm a Web Designer and I do a little bit of PHP developing, I want to learn a PHP framework (I'm learning Laravel), but I do not get the idea of integrating an HTML template that I've already made with the framework.
Thank you for your generosity.

Comment: I don't know what an "HTML template" is supposed to be. That's a very vague term and can mean different things in different contexts. Please clarify a bit.

Comment: Well, an HTML template to me is a set of HTML pages designed to be used in a web project (website, web application...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is a backend language... `PHP` Meaning it outputs the HTML and contains the logic that is needed to build relevant `HTML`.

`HTML` is used by interpreted by the browsers. Its static.

But tbh, this is such a silly answer that the real answer is:

```
Read something about HTML then once you've read that...

Read something about PHP
```

You will see they are completely different things.

Comment: I see your point here, and i know this :) But it's a little bit hard for me to understand these concepts of Templating in PHP since i'm an HTML designer and a beginer PHP developer.

Comment: I still hope information on the two helped you somewhat :)

Comment: Well sorry I can't give you any more information, but `HTML` is called frontend and php is backend. If it has helped you in StackOverflow you normally click the tick to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> A Static Website (HTML)

A static website is the simplest kind of website you can build. Static websites are written in HTML and CSS only, with no scripting. The only form of interactivity on a static website is hyperlinks.

If you intend your website to be a small one (3 pages or less), then a static website might be the easiest way to go. But if you want to share elements between pages (such as logos or menus), you’ll have to duplicate the HTML on each page.

Static websites are easier to make than dynamic websites, because they require less coding and technical knowledge. However, fully static websites are very uncommon these days, since there is so much that scripting can do.

> A Dynamic Website (PHP)

A dynamic website is a website that not only uses HTML and CSS, but includes website scripting as well. There are two main reasons why you’d want to use website scripting on your site:

you want an interactive web app that people can use, not just read
you want to be able to share HTML code between your pages.
This website is a dynamic website, for both of the above reasons. It’s not a full-blown web app like Facebook or Google, but it does have interactive elements like contact forms and search boxes. This website also shares the same HTML code for the header, menu and sidebar between all pages of the site.

If you want a dynamic site, you will need to learn a coding language such as JavaScript, PHP, Ruby on Rails or ASP.NET.

Comment: This is not my question bro !!